# MS Outlook 2016 Ribbon Scaling issues

Tags: outlook, vsto, ribbonx

When the width of an Outlook Explorer or Inspector window is reduced the ribbon changes. In my VSTO addin can I influence how the scaling happens with the Office Ribbon?

Further at a certain width the tab becomes a single icon with a small arrow which when clicked the buttons/elements of the tab appear in a pop-up.  How can I set the icon that appears in this case?

Below is my current XML for the tab.

I have also added a picture of how my ribbon looks when the window is made narrow.

I am not able to find a new XML Markup from Microsoft is this really the latest version [[MS-CUSTOMUI2]: Custom UI XML Markup Version 2 Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui2/bad56c21-7b15-41bc-af32-8b5afe6e922e)

[image: Image of narrow ribbon with single button and arrow]

```
<tabs>
<!-- Creates a new App Tab on the inspector toolbar-->
<tab idMso="TabReadMessage">
  <group id="AppGroup" label="App">
    <!-- A toggle or ON/OFF button to Encrypt or Decrypt an email and show the current encryption -->
    <toggleButton id="insDecryptButton"
        getLabel="insDecryptButton_getLabel"
        size="large"
        onAction="insDecryptButton_ButtonClick"
        getImage="insDecryptButton_getImage"
        getSupertip="insDecryptButton_getSupertip"
        getScreentip="insDecryptButton_getScreentip"
        getPressed="insDecryptButton_getPressed"
                  getVisible="insDecryptButton_getVisible"/>

    <!-- A Button with drop down that shows all the File Numbers in the Email. If there are no file numbers this will not appear. -->
    <dynamicMenu id="insMenu"
               getLabel="insMenu_getLabel"
               size="large"
               getImage="insMenu_getImage"
                 getVisible="insMenu_getVisible"
                 getSupertip="insMenu_getSupertip"
                getScreentip="insMenu_getScreentip"
               getContent="insMenu_getContent"/>

    <!-- Button to upload the email or attachments to IPAS -->
    <dynamicMenu id="upMenu"
               getLabel="upMenu_getLabel"
               size="large"
               getImage="upMenu_getImage"
                 getVisible="upMenu_getVisible"
                 getSupertip="upMenu_getSupertip"
                getScreentip="upMenu_getScreentip"
               getContent="upMenu_getContent"/>
  </group>
</tab>
```

Comment: You can assign an image to the group using `getImage` as well.

Comment: thank you. I was searching for something in the tab and ignored the group element. Make your comment the answer if you want.

Comment: No worries mate. Glad I could help. I have a bunch of examples of VSTO Addins in GitHub if it helps.  https://github.com/aduguid

Answer (score 0):

Office applications perform the scaling optimization on its own. There is no new schema for that. Instead, as other poster noticed, you need to provide the `getImage` callback to all your `group` controls. It should look like this:

```
 C#: IPictureDisp GetImage(IRibbonControl control)
 VBA: Sub GetImage(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef image)
 C++: HRESULT GetImage([in] IRibbonControl *pControl, [out, retval] IPictureDisp ** ppdispImage)
 Visual Basic: Function GetImage(control as IRibbonControl) as IPictureDisp
```

Calling the `Invadiate` or `InvalidateControl` you may get a new image displayed (so, your callback will be invoked).

Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12))

If you want to know more about dynamic customizations you may take a look at:

- [OfficeTalk: Display and Hide Tabs, Groups, and Controls on the Microsoft Office Ribbon User Interface (Part 1 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/officetalk2007/ee390805(v=office.11))
- [OfficeTalk: Display and Hide Tabs, Groups, and Controls on the Microsoft Office Ribbon User Interface (Part 2 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/officetalk2007/ee633442(v=office.11))